# How to convert SVG to Drawable resource in code

Tags: java, android, svg, vector, android-drawable

Is it possible to create a `Drawable` object from an SVG file in code? I'm aware of the functionality in Android Studio where you can upload an SVG file, and it will create a new XML drawable resource file from that which can be displayed in your app. But, I need to do this conversion at runtime, as I will be getting SVG files from a server via network requests.

Comment: There are several SVG rendering libraries in [the Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/96?sort=updated).

Comment: I think you can use android Webview to display SVGs.